# Getting proper callback for multiple listbox

Tags: python-3.x

I have python code which contains two listboxes. One contains list of animals, and one contains fruits. My code is working properly when i clicking in only 1 listbox, for exampl in animals. As soon as i change to Fruits listbox, on the first selection the code prints out the last selected animal as well.

How i can avoid the duplicate printing when i change between the 2 lisboxes?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

animals_listbox = Listbox(root)
animals_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
fruits_listbox=Listbox(root)
fruits_listbox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

for animal in animals:
    animals_listbox.insert(END, animal)

for fruit in fruits:
    fruits_listbox.insert(END, fruit)

def onselectanimals(event):
    print("Selected animal: ", animals_listbox.get(ANCHOR), event.widget)


def onselectfruits(event):
    print("Selected fruit: ", fruits_listbox.get(ANCHOR), event.widget)



animals_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselectanimals)
fruits_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselectfruits)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you could mark mine as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed both of your functions to this and it worked:

```
def onselectanimals(event):
    sel = animals_listbox.curselection()
    try:
        print("Selected animal: ", animals_listbox.get(sel), event.widget)
    except:
        pass


def onselectfruits(event):
    sel1 = fruits_listbox.curselection()
    try:
        print("Selected fruit: ", fruits_listbox.get(sel1), event.widget)
    except:
        pass
```

I am ignoring the error that comes with `try` and `except` blocks. Its not the perfect way i guess, but it is a way around :D

**EDIT :**

Found out about this later only but, the easiest and **PERFECT WAY** to fix this is while defining the listbox, make it like (here you dont have to change the functions like before):

```
animals_listbox = Listbox(root,exportselection=0)
fruits_listbox = Listbox(root,exportselection=0)
```

`exportselection=0` argument is the mechanism where the first selection of the user is cleared and then something new is selected.

Quoting @Jason Coon

> By default, the selection is exported to the X selection mechanism. If you have more than one listbox on the screen, this really messes things up for the poor user. If he selects something in one listbox, and then selects something in another, the original selection is cleared.

For more reference, check [here](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-exportselection)

**EDIT 2 :**

Also updating the answer, to show as if just one of the item is only selected, with the extra solution you gave:

```
def onselectanimals(event):
    animal_listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
    print("Selected animal: ", animals_listbox.get(ANCHOR), event.widget)

def onselectfruits(event):
    fruits_listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
    print("Selected fruit: ", fruits_listbox.get(ANCHOR), event.widget)
```

Cheers